# What do valuation rings mean geometrically?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If I understand correctly:

- Given an algebraic curve $C$ and a point $P \in C$, the stalk at $P$ is always a local ring.
- The stalk at $P$ is a discrete valuation ring iff $P$ is a non-singular point of $C$.

Now "valuation ring" is an intermediate notion between "local ring" and "discrete valuation ring." But I'm not sure what it means geometrically.

> **Question.** What do valuation rings mean geometrically?

Comment: Note that a *Noetherian* valuation ring is either a DVR or a field, so you have to to consider of non-Noetherian schemes to see any new phenomena.

Comment: @Hurkyl, okay. Thanks!